# Failed to import itextasian (Not available Failure to find com.lowagie:itextasian:jar:2.0.7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: java, maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextasian</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to import this library in my pom.xml file, but I was getting the error of Not available Failure to find com.lowagie:itextasian:jar:2.0.7 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, but when I check in the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itextasian/2.0.7, this library is still there for me to import.

May I know how can I import the itextasian? I have tried to import the jar file directly in intellij, but I will be getting error from the existing itext pdf library.

Please be noted that because I am using the com.lowagie's itext 2.1.5, so if possible I would like to use the itextasian from com.lowagie as well.

Comment: Please, post your maven `settings.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itextasian also states that the artifact has been relocated to `com.itextpdf:itext-asian`. Change your dependency to the relocated artifact and it should be possible for you to download it.

Also note that `mvnrepository.com` is not an actual maven repository host but merely an aggregator of information found in repositories. Information available on `mvnrepository.com` might be outdated/not in sync with your maven repo settings configuration.

You might also want to notice that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itextasian/2.0.7 says

> this artifact is located at EmergyaPub repository (http://nexus.emergya.es/nexus/content/repositories/public/)

You need to add this repo to your maven config **if you trust it**.